# UIButton's position not displayed correctly

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I'm dealing with Buttons in Swift right now. Well, it seems like Swift is not setting the position of my UIButton correctly, because it's appearing off the screen, when I want it in the center. Here's my code, did I do anything wrong?

```
import SpriteKit
import UIKit

class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    /* Setup your scene here */

    let button = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.System)

    let buttonImage = UIImage(named: "Button")
    button.frame = CGRectMake(self.frame.size.width / 2, self.frame.size.height / 2, 100, 86) // x, y, width, height
    button.setBackgroundImage(buttonImage, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: "buttonAction", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    self.view?.addSubview(button)

}

func buttonAction (sender: UIButton!) {

    print("Button tapped")

}
```

Please help :/

Comment: Instead of  `self.frame.size...` try `self.view.frame.size...`

Comment: @u54r that fixes the problem of the button being displayed off screen, but the positioning is still weird, thanks for answering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this may help.

```
import SpriteKit
import UIKit

class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    /* Setup your scene here */

    let button = UIButton()

    let buttonImage = UIImage(named: "Button")

    button.frame.size = CGSizeMake(100, 86)
    button.center = self.view.center;
    button.setBackgroundImage(buttonImage, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: "buttonAction", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    self.view?.addSubview(button)

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that definitely gets the button centered. But I guess there's no way of fixing this positioning issue...

Comment: Is your issue fixed ?

Comment: yea kinda, but now I have another issue. Every time I press the button, it takes me to the AppDelegate.swift file and gives me an error: _Thread 1: signal SIGABRT_; the console description is pretty long, so I'm not gonna write that, do you have any idea? `class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {` that line gets marked red

Comment: If your issue fixed then please mark answer as accepted and ask another question with code to solve your new issue. Thanks